# Forward Declaration of Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a template class with a friend template function. I currently have the following code and it is working:

```
template<class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    template<class U, class W>
    friend Vector<U> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<U>& rhs);
}

template<class U, class W>
Vector<U> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<U>& rhs)
{
  // Multiplication
}
```

I would prefer for my solution to have forward declaration of the friend function so that I can have the security benefits and one-to-one correspondence that it provides compared to my current method.  I tried the following but keep running into errors.

```
template<class T>
class Vector;

template<class T, class W>
Vector<T> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs);

template<class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    friend Vector<T> (::operator*<>)(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs);
}

template<class T, class W>
Vector<T> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs)
{
  // Multiplication
}
```

Comment: y not use the original `friend` declaration

Comment: With the original version, all template instantiations of Vector are friends with all template instantiations of operator*.  I would prefer the second solution where Vectors would not allow all different template instantiations to be friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost had it. You just needed to make the function a single parameter template when you friend it. The following compiles on g++ 4.5 although since I can't test the instantiation with your test case I'm not 100% sure it will solve your real problem.

```
template<class T>
class Vector;

template<class T, class W>
Vector<T> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs);

template<class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    template<class W>
    friend Vector<T> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs);
};

template<class T, class W>
Vector<T> operator*(const W lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs)
{
  // Multiplication
}
```

Comment: The code compiles, [but it won' link](http://ideone.com/KIT4lV). The friend function and the free function template are different deductions.

Comment: I get the same error as WhozCraig using the GNU compiler. It works on Visual Studio C++ however.